# Using CASE with GROUP BY

Tags: t-sql, group-by, case

I have the following query in T-SQL:

```
SELECT dbo.table2.device, 
    dbo.table2.CREATETIME AS create_time,
    CASE WHEN dbo.table1.ACTIONID = 1 
        THEN dbo.table1.startstop 
    END AS start_time,
    CASE WHEN dbo.table1.ACTIONID  = 2 
        THEN dbo.table1.startstop 
    END AS stop_time,
    dbo.table2.collect_time
FROM dbo.table2
JOIN dbo.table1 ON dbo.table1.CREATETIME = dbo.table2.CREATETIME;
```

...which gives me a result table with several rows, each a duplicate with once the start- once the end- time (sql time - shortened for simplicity) - the other being NULL - e.g.:

```
device | create_time | start_time | stop_time | collect_time
1      | 0000001     | 0000001    | NULL      | 0000001
1      | 0000001     | NULL       | 0000002   | 0000001
```

I want to group these two rows (with create_time as ID) so I get them into one.... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate (`SUM`) these columns:

```
SELECT dbo.table2.device, 
    dbo.table2.CREATETIME AS create_time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.table1.ACTIONID = 1 
        THEN dbo.table1.startstop ELSE 0
    END) AS start_time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.table1.ACTIONID  = 2 
        THEN dbo.table1.startstop ELSE 0
    END) AS stop_time,
    dbo.table2.collect_time
FROM dbo.table2
JOIN dbo.table1 ON dbo.table1.CREATETIME = dbo.table2.CREATETIME
GROUP BY dbo.table2.device, dbo.table2.CREATETIME, dbo.table2.collect_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I suppose using subquery would work out as well

```
SELECT
X.Device
,sum(X.start_time)
,sum(X.stop_time)
,X.collect_time
from(
SELECT dbo.table2.device, 
    dbo.table2.CREATETIME AS create_time,
    CASE WHEN dbo.table1.ACTIONID = 1 
        THEN dbo.table1.startstop 
    END AS start_time,
    CASE WHEN dbo.table1.ACTIONID  = 2 
        THEN dbo.table1.startstop 
    END AS stop_time,
    dbo.table2.collect_time
FROM dbo.table2
JOIN dbo.table1 ON dbo.table1.CREATETIME = dbo.table2.CREATETIME) AS X
group by
X.Device, X.collect_time
```

Comment: I might compare these two versions performance- wise... thanks for the input!